# expression by boxplot in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, I want to compare the expression value of any two genes by boxplot, how to approach this, this is samples of my data set:

```
structure(list(gene_id = structure(6:11, .Label = c("__alignment_not_unique", 
"__ambiguous", "__no_feature", "__not_aligned", "__too_low_aQual", 
"ENSG00000000005", "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", 
"ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036", "ENSG00000001084", 
"ENSG00000001167", "ENSG00000001460", "ENSG00000001461", "ENSG00000001497", 
"ENSG00000001561", "ENSG00000001617", "ENSG00000001626", "ENSG00000001629", 
"ENSG00000001630", "ENSG00000001631", "ENSG00000002016", "ENSG00000002079", 
"ENSG00000002330", "ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000002586", "ENSG00000002587", 
"ENSG00000002726", "ENSG00000002745", "ENSG00000002746", "ENSG00000002822", 
"ENSG00000002834", "ENSG00000002919", "ENSG00000002933", "ENSG00000003056", 
"ENSG00000003096", "ENSG00000003137", "ENSG00000003147", "ENSG00000003249", 
"ENSG00000003393", "ENSG00000003400", "ENSG00000003402", "ENSG00000003436", 
"ENSG00000003509", "ENSG00000003756", "ENSG00000003987", "ENSG00000003989", 
"ENSG00000004059", "ENSG00000004139", "ENSG00000004142", "ENSG00000004399", 
"ENSG00000285989", "ENSG00000285990", "ENSG00000285991", "ENSG00000285992", 
"ENSG00000285993", "ENSG00000285994"), class = "factor"), expr = c(6L, 
754L, 447L, 426L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

head of the data set:

```
        gene_id         expr
           <fct>       <int>
1   ENSG00000000005     6
2   ENSG00000000419     754
3   ENSG00000000457     447
4   ENSG00000000460     426
5   ENSG00000000938     5
6   ENSG00000000971     1
```

I tried @r2evans code (which is great help):

```
par(mar = c(5,12,2,2))
barplot(df1$expr, names.arg = df1$gene_id, horiz = TRUE, las = 1)
```

I get this:
[image]

The second trial:

```
dat$family <- substr(as.character(dat$gene_id), 1, nchar(as.character(dat$gene_id))-2)
boxplot(expr ~ family, data = dat, horizontal = TRUE, las = 2)
```

I get this:
[image]

Comment: sorry @r2evans , I was reading your comment about the editing and I was trying to fix it, I apologize, I was trying to respond promptly.

Comment: no worries, just pointing it out, sorry if it came across as annoyed or upset

Comment: I appreciate your support, if you still want to edit the question, go ahead, I won't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat <- structure(list(gene_id = structure(6:11, .Label = c("__alignment_not_unique", "__ambiguous", "__no_feature", "__not_aligned", "__too_low_aQual", "ENSG00000000005", "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036", "ENSG00000001084", "ENSG00000001167", "ENSG00000001460", "ENSG00000001461", "ENSG00000001497", "ENSG00000001561", "ENSG00000001617", "ENSG00000001626", "ENSG00000001629", "ENSG00000001630", "ENSG00000001631", "ENSG00000002016", "ENSG00000002079", "ENSG00000002330", "ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000002586", "ENSG00000002587", "ENSG00000002726", "ENSG00000002745", "ENSG00000002746", "ENSG00000002822", "ENSG00000002834", "ENSG00000002919", "ENSG00000002933", "ENSG00000003056", "ENSG00000003096", "ENSG00000003137", "ENSG00000003147", "ENSG00000003249", "ENSG00000003393", "ENSG00000003400", "ENSG00000003402", "ENSG00000003436", "ENSG00000003509", "ENSG00000003756", "ENSG00000003987", "ENSG00000003989", "ENSG00000004059", "ENSG00000004139", "ENSG00000004142", "ENSG00000004399", "ENSG00000285989", "ENSG00000285990", "ENSG00000285991", "ENSG00000285992", "ENSG00000285993", "ENSG00000285994"), class = "factor"), expr = c(6L, 754L, 447L, 426L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
par(mar = c(5,12,2,2))
barplot(dat$expr, names.arg = dat$gene_id, horiz = TRUE, las = 1)
```

[image: barplot]

---

**Updated** for "families":

```r
dat$family <- substr(as.character(dat$gene_id), 1, nchar(as.character(dat$gene_id))-2)
boxplot(expr ~ family, data = dat, horizontal = TRUE, las = 2)
```

[image: boxplot of families]

---

**Update #2**: there is likely no way to really make base graphics or `ggplot2` deal with that many factors well, in an elegant manner. I suggest you look into different rendering formats, such as HTML (or pdf) with sparklines.

I'll demonstrate with `kableExtra`, though since the functions being used here are recent, they are not in CRAN so you'll need to `devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")`.

After that:

```r
dat$family <- substr(as.character(dat$gene_id), 1, nchar(as.character(dat$gene_id))-2)

library(kableExtra)
alldat <- split(dat$expr, dat$family)
kbl(data.frame(family = names(alldat), expr = rep("", length(alldat)))) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(., 2, image = spec_boxplot(alldat)) %>%
  htmltools::browsable()
```

[image: kableExtra output]

There is a *lot* more configuration you can do to this, but it's a start. I suggest you read `kableExtra`'s vignettes, particularly https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html (or https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf), as they demonstrate some of the newer sparkline functionality.

Comment: I tried this @r2evans `par(mar = c(5,12,2,2))
barplot(df1$expr, names.arg = df1$gene_id, horiz = TRUE, las = 1)` I update the question with your code and the plot that I got. Are these for two genes? I want to try two genes only. I'm still learning.

Comment: can I make 'fake families' by the last digits of the IDs and create two box plots based on any of those i.e. xxx419 xxx457 xxx460 --> would all go into a family of '400' and so on?

Comment: I updated the question @r2evans , it was my mistake, I cut the top and the bottom of the data and paste them, thank you for the note, about your answer, I'm new this, how do I know that I'm comparing two genes only? the data has 58734 rows including the redundancies, which I tried to remove but no luck, the redundancies start with double underscore "__"